# Perfectly Center li inline block elements?

Tags: html, css

This following inline block li elements are not perfectly centered, I can send the full code if you need it. Do you know a way to have them perfectly centered keeping their position at default?

```
  <div id="abovenavigation">

        <ul id="container">

            <li><a href="index.html"><h1 class="Home">HOME</h1></a></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="About">ABOUT</h1></li><!--
            --><li><h1 class="Blog">BLOG</h1></li><!--
            -->

        </ul><!--ends container--> 

        </div><!--ends upper navigation-->


<div id="undernavigation">

            <ul id="container">
            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Albus.Severus.Vitanza" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src="Facebook.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Facebookhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Facebook.png'"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Promoetheus" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src="Twitter.png" width="53px" height="50px" onclick="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Twitterhov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Twitter.png'" /></a></li>
            <li><a href:"mailto:gaaren03@gmail.com"><img class="mailto" src="Mailto.png" width="53px" height="50px" title="gaaren03@gmail.com" onclick="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseover="this.src='Mailtohov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Mailto.png'" /></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--ends undernavigation-->



li {
    margin:0 20px;
    font-size:18px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Margin 0 auto is not working as well, as u can observe the first Li element will be a bit towards the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add text-align: center to the ul. :)
codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGgpLK

```
li {
  margin:0 20px;
  font-size:18px;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I've just done it but still the same, if u want i can send u the full code in snippet

Comment: Go ahead! I think there's some other styling that may be interfering with the align.

Comment: Also check out the codepen I've linked if you wanna figure out on your own.

Comment: Man observe the codepen, it's like this in my own sheet. Look at bloog, it is more towards the left, it is not perfectly on the middle, and check "home", it is more towards the right, it is not starting from the middle in your codepen as well

Answer (score 0):

You could either give the list items a fixed width seeing as you have them set to display: inline-block. Or if you are supporting IE8 and above you could set the ul to display:table with a 100% width and the li to display: table-cell.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/craigliggs/3f9td74q/)

```
ul {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:18px;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Man the problem is that the whole ul starts a bit from right, it's not perfectly centered, oculd it be another element causing it? I can send full html

Comment: Ah, I think this is due to the whitespace in the HTML. Remove the whitespace between the opening ul and first li (or add a comment like you have done between list items). This happens because you are displaying the elements inline.